# Can I resize the window width from a web app?

Tags: unity, webapps

I'm developing a webapp and in Ubuntu 14.04 I have this doubt:

Can I resize the window width from a web app? How?

---

For @terdon question:

Code: https://launchpad.net/unity-webapps-telegram

The app is opening always like this:

[image]

I'd like open the app with this width:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean to say the width of your app.

Comment: Yes, In Ubuntu 14.04 the window has always a big width for my webapp. I'd like to launch with less width. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain. Add a screenshot perhaps? Show us the relevant code?

Comment: @terdon Updated post for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the kindness of a developer, I can give some information to my questions.

I can't resize the window as a W3C standard operation; There isn't an explicit APIs for that, and generally move away from letting apps manage their sizes, to prepare for the desktop convergence.
You should assume that the shell will present you in an appopriate way; You must to add / obseve some viewport metadata at some point to know whether you are a side-stage app or a fullscreen one.

Best regards!